# Fast access to locale variable in a cpdef cython function

Tags: python, reference, arguments, cython

I need fast access from python to a variable used in an algorithm written in cython:
Here is the pseudocode:

```
cpdef(double a, double b):
    while a < 100.:
        # some long-term calculations
        a = x
```

Because I call it from python I use a cpdef function. The user needs a hint of the progress of the long-term calculation. This can be done with access to the "a" variable. But it is not possible to use reference arguments (double &a) or pointers (double *a) in a cpdef function (compiler errors). How is it possible to get fast access to the local variable of the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very standard way to display progress is to use a callback, this isn't specific to cython, but is general python and so works just as well in cython. A callback based approach will work in both single threaded and multithreaded programs, unlike some kind of reference which would only work for a multithreaded program. Using the callback incurs a very slight performance penalty, but if your code is only going to call the callback 100 times over a few seconds (or however long the job is that a progress bar is needed for) you will not notice the performance impact at all, as cython code can easily call a callback into python 30,000,000 times per/s. As such, unless you're doing something very different to displaying progress a callback should work perfectly.

Here is a working example:

```
cpdef foo(double a, double b, object callback=None):
    while a < 100:
        a += 1
        # some long-term calculations
        if callback is not None:
            callback(a)


def progress(a):
    print(a)

foo(0, 0, progress)
```

Using a callback makes it easy to call any kind of code. In the example I just use a python function, but you could also pass in a method on an object instance (a 'bound method') to print to a screen, update GUI elements, send a message etc. If the callback is going to do a lot of work just make sure you don't call it too often (i.e. by only calling it once for every hundred passes over the calculation).